# How to iterate "For each object that has a value" in powershell

Tags: powershell, wmi, powershell-4.0

I am using gwmi to return a lot of different information on a system. I used the following command to get the network information:

```
$networkInfo = gwmi win32_networkadapterconfiguration
```

which returns an array of network adapters and information on them. Since there are a number of network adapters that I am not intersted in, how do I filter out the "bad" ones? I would guess I need to get just the ones with an IPv4 address, but how do I specify that?

Do I have to use an if nested in a for loop, or is there a quicker way?

psuedo code:

```
for ($i=0; $i -lt $networkInfo[$i].length; $i++){
    if($networkInfo[$i].IPAddress has a value){
        #do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: Use the [Where-Object](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee177028.aspx) filter. This can then be piped to [Foreach-Object](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176828.aspx) or itself used as "for" input.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As was mentioned in the comments, you can use the [Where-Object](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee177028.aspx) command to filter result in the pipeline. For your specific needs this should work:

```
gwmi win32_networkadapterconfiguration | where IPAddress -NE $NULL
```

Comment: You could get rid of the quotes on `"IPAddress"` if you like.

Comment: @Dangph - You are correct sir. Force of habit that is hard to break.